# How do you jump to the first non-whitespace character in a line with vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a long time Eclipse user. When using Eclipse, if I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> while my cursor is in the whitespace that precedes the line's first non-whitespace character, the cursor jumps to the first non-whitespace character.  If I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, it will insert a tab (or requisite number of spaces) as expected.

In vscode, if my cursor is in the whitespace before the first character and I hit tab, the line gets indented further.  I'm looking to be able to jump my cursor to the first non-whitespace character on the line like I do with Eclipse.

I've read through all of the settings and googled a bit but can't find this addressed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press the <kbd>Home</kbd> key. If the cursor is already on the first non-whitespace character, pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> will move the cursor to the first character on the line instead.

Comment: If you want to rebind the keyboard shortcut, the name of the command is `cursorHome`. If you change this, you probably also want to rebind `cursorHomeSelect` to `shift+${keybind}`